# Creating Menu in Python

Tags: python

```
menu
1. Plot Graph
2. Exit/Quit
```

When the user enter 1,

This code will be run, so instead of when user enter 1 and something is printed, how can i run the code below when the user press 1

Comment: What is the below dump of code for ?

Comment: the code is for plotting graphs from my txt files

Comment: Ok. That goes inside the main(). check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235699/creating-menu-in-python/25235760#25235760

Comment: You should restrict your post to a single (small) question whenever possible and ask a new, separate question for the rest

Comment: hi tobias, I will bear that in mind, thanks for the advise, I will post a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
menu = raw_input("Please choose a operation from the menu:")

if menu == '1':
  run_the_code()
elif menu == '2':
  exit_the_code()
else:
  print "No such option!"
```

Is this what you want? Users have to press enter to proceed.

Comment: Using Python 2-only `raw_input`, but Python 3-style `print`, in the same answer is likely to confuse the user, no matter which version of Python he's on.

Comment: Oops, thank you for the advise. I have changed the print function to keep consistency.

Comment: how do i put all my code for plotting to the "run_the_code()"

Comment: @robotbob33 `def run_the_code():` mayhaps? If you don't know that yet you might want to consult the Python tutorials a bit more, they're quite good

Comment: You indentation is wrong in your updated code. from the with open() line.

Comment: so i should shift every thing below def main(): a little bit to the right?

Comment: i tried shifting everything to the right a bit but i got an error at 'with open..' (i had updated my code again, btw)

Comment: @robotbob33 You're new to StackOverflow, so welcome! However you shouldn't use comments and edits for _new_ questions but rather ask them separately. You might want to take a quick look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get an understanding how SO differs from a classical forum, which may take some time for you to adjust to but trust me, it is worth the effort. And the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) site is _very_ helpful to get assistance efficiently

Answer (score 0):

Put all your code inside `main()` function. No need to press enter, it reads the key pressed.

```
import msvcrt

option = msvcrt.getch()
if option == '1': 
   main()
else:
   exit()
```

FYI: https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html

Comment: Linux? is it the same?

Comment: @robotbob33 This will solve windows/unix problem - http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to do this with python dictionaries by storing the key as the choice and the value as a reference to the function you want executed. This is preferred when giving many options because it eliminates the need to set up all the if statements and it makes the addition or removal of options easier. Plus I believe I read somewhere it is more efficient but I am not sure if this is actually true. And because it is simplier it is more pythonic!

The code to create a menu like you ask for would look something like this.

```
options = {     1 : run_code,
                2 : dont_run_code,
}

user_input = raw_input("1 or 2")
options[user_input]()
```

which means of course that you would have to place your code within a function (to do that the syntax looks like this)

```
def function(parameters):
    do stuff
```

Notice how in the dictionary the functions are stored without the `()`. This is done because without the parenthesis it is a reference to the function itself (if you do a print you will see it give you the memory address), with the parenthesis the function will execute. Then you simply call the function by adding parenthesis to the dictiorary lookup like this `options[user_input]()`

Note: In other languages I would recomend looking into a switch statement, python however does not have one.